# Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554) core.d.ts(8054, 47): An argument for 'opts' was not provided

Tags: arguments, nativescript, decorator, viewchild

This is a part of my code that I get this error:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
core.d.ts(8054, 47): An argument for 'opts' was not provided.
```

from here:

```
import {ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core"; 
import {RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType} from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";

export class DrawerPage implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) protected drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent; 
    protected drawer: SideDrawerType;

    constructor(private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() { 
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer; 
        this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); 
    }

    protected openDrawer() { 
        this.drawer.showDrawer(); 
    }

    protected closeDrawer() { 
        this.drawer.closeDrawer(); 
    }
}
```

I can't understand what is the problem? I am new learner who follows a tutorial video to learn NativeScript!

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 8 , ViewChild takes 2 parameters:

Try like this:

```
@ViewChild('nameInput', { static: false }) nameInputRef: ElementRef;
```

*Explanation:*

**{ static: false }**

If you set static false, the component ALWAYS gets initialized after the view initialization in time for the ngAfterViewInit/ngAfterContentInit callback functions.

**{ static: true}**

If you set static true, the initialization will take place at the view initialization at ngOnInit

By default you can use { static: false }. If you are creating a dynamic view and want to use the template reference variable, then you should use { static: true}

For more info, you can read this [here](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/angular-viewchild-static-property-in-ng8/)

Thank you.

Comment: in your case add this ```@ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent, { static: false }) protected drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent; ```

Comment: was this correct answer? if this answer is correct please be kind to put the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer` and that is not supported by latest version of Nativscript.This package has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-telerik-ui).

For side drawer, use [nativescript-ui-sidedrawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer).